# Selenium WebDriver: Random click a row button

Tags: java, selenium, testng

How to click a row in table by randomly? 
I know how to using Random class to iterate the List but don't know how to click the button of the specific row after randomize due to xpath different.

Please provide me some idea and guideline on how to solve this.

ps: I got some idea, the button is located at the last column, so i just click on the last column button.

Comment: You can get list of elements. Then you generate random number from 0 to list size - 1. After that you get from list that element and provide click on it

Comment: Any others answers you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way to get random number from 1 to 10

```
 int min=1; 
    int max=9;
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);

    System.out.println(randomNum);
```

If we think its row number, then, need to click on last column of that row.

i am imaging last column as td[6] then path will looks like

```
 "//table/tbody/tr["+randomNum+"]/td[6]/button"
```